# How do I remove the middle element out of a char array and resize the array using only pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Title basically says it all.

I need to remove the middle element out of my char array.

Then I need to resize it while only using pointers.

I can't use any array or [] brackets outside of creating the static array and dynamic new array declerations such as int `*temp = new int[6];`

This is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch,      system("pause") or input loop */


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// Static Arrays    
char myChar[14] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'n', 'd', '!', '\0'};

// Pointers

char *temp3 = myChar;

char *temp4 = newChar;

cout<<"\n\nThis is the original element for the char array.\n\n";
cout<<"\t";
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    cout<<"["<<*temp3<<"] ";
    temp3++;
}


    temp3 = myChar;
    cout<<"\n\nThis prints out every other character in the char array.\n\n";
    cout<<"\t";
    for(int i = 0; i < 13/2; i++)
    {
        temp3++;
        cout<<"["<<*temp3<<"] ";
        temp3++;
    }


// Attempt at splitting it by the first six digits
temp3 = myChar;
cout<<"\n\nThis prints out every other character in the char array.\n\n";
cout<<"\t";
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{

}


return 0;}
```

Comment: Note: you can use `char myChar[14] = "Hello Friend!";` instead of `char myChar[14] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'n', 'd', '!', '\0'};`

Comment: What is "resize char array"? I think you can't resize `char myChar[14]`.

Comment: Note: `hoge[fuga]` is equivalent to `*((hoge)+(fuga))`, so both can be used.

Comment: Arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: I believe you can resize it by using a pointer. i.e. 'char *temp = new char[6];'

Comment: Your belief is incorrect. All you've done there is dynamically allocate a new, completely different array, which has no relation whatsoever to your original array.

Comment: You can allocate new array with new size, copy the contents of old array and assign the new array again on a pointer, but for static array like `char myChar[14]` it cannot be done.